# Sign mistake in Fourier transform of $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I want to calculate the distributional Fourier transform of $u(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$ in one dimension in the distributional sense as $u\notin L^1$.

I use the distributional definition of the Fourier transform (denoted with $\mathcal{F}$). In the following, I will use the well known formula for $\mathcal{F}(\frac{1}{x^2+1})(\xi) = \pi e^{-|\xi|}$ as well as the formula $\mathcal{F}( x u ) = (i\partial) \,\mathcal{F}(u)$. Note that the latter formula also yields for distributions. For $f\in L^1$ functions, I use the convention

$$\mathcal{F}(f) (\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-i x \xi } \,\text{d}x. $$

This gives that $$\mathcal{F}(u) (\xi)=\mathcal{F}(x  \frac{1}{x^2+1}) (\xi)= (i\partial_\xi) \pi e^{-|\xi|} = -i\pi e^{-|\xi|} \text{sgn}(\xi),$$ which is correct up to a minus (See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20transform%20(x%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)))). Where is my mistake?  Indeed WolframAlpha uses the same [sign convention](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html) as I do. (neglecting factors of $2\pi$).

Comment: How does sgn work for complex valued functions? I would try to clear up any issues there and perhaps your problem will be resolved.

Comment: $x, \xi \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computation is correct!

Despite [what WA itself is saying](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_*MathWorld.FourierTransform-), it doesn't use the definition on MathWorld, but the definition in Mathematica, which employs an unexpected sign convention.

From the [Mathematica documentation of the **FourierTransform** command](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FourierTransform.html):

- The Fourier transform of a function is by default defined to be
  $$
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{i\omega t} dt
  .
  $$
- Other definitions are used in some scientific and technical fields.
- Different choices of definitions can be specified using the option **FourierParameters**.